# Hamburger menu item collapses into 2 lines

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, elementor

I have built a Wordpress website with a hamburger menu on mobile.
Here's the menu's HTML:

```
<div class="elementor elementor-1303 elementor-type-section">
    <div class="elementor-inner">
        <div class="elementor-section-wrap">
            <section data-id="84451c8" class="elementor-element elementor-element-84451c8 elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-section elementor-top-section" data-element_type="section">
                <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-row">
                        <div data-id="32037fc" class="elementor-element elementor-element-32037fc elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
                            <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                                    <div data-id="01cf21a" class="elementor-element elementor-element-01cf21a elementor-widget elementor-widget-spacer" data-element_type="spacer.default">
                                        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                            <div class="elementor-spacer">
                                                <div class="elementor-spacer-inner"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section data-id="70032df" class="elementor-element elementor-element-70032df elementor-section-full_width elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-section elementor-top-section" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;,&quot;background_image&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;&quot;}}" data-element_type="section">
                <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-row">
                        <div data-id="14d0f8d4" class="elementor-element elementor-element-14d0f8d4 elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
                            <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                                    <div data-id="5fa72fd" class="elementor-element elementor-element-5fa72fd elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="about-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                                        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#regulation-mobile"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">?מהי רגולציה</span></span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.688em; font-weight: 400;"></span><p></p></a></h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div data-id="4e7c2bc" class="elementor-element elementor-element-4e7c2bc elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="about-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                                        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#maya-about-mobile"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">?אודות</span></span></a></h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div data-id="45788e2" class="elementor-element elementor-element-45788e2 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="about-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                                        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#fit-mobile"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">?למי זה מתאים</span></span></a></h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div data-id="2a24b44" class="elementor-element elementor-element-2a24b44 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="contact-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                                        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#solution-mobile"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">פתרונות</span></span></a></h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div data-id="fcd1ddb" class="elementor-element elementor-element-fcd1ddb elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="contact-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                                        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#contact-mobile"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">צור קשר</span></span></a></h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <section data-id="23d1d02" class="elementor-element elementor-element-23d1d02 elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-section elementor-inner-section" data-element_type="section">
                                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                                            <div class="elementor-row">
                                                <div data-id="b6d5052" class="elementor-element elementor-element-b6d5052 elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-inner-column" data-element_type="column">
                                                    <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                                        <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                                                            <div data-id="4f72658" class="elementor-element elementor-element-4f72658 mobilemenucontact elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" id="mobilemenucontact" data-element_type="text-editor.default">
                                                                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                                                    <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix">
                                                                        <p style="text-align: center;"><img class="email-mobile" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Untitled-1.svg" width="33" height="33">&nbsp;<img class="facebook-mobile" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Untitled-2.svg" width="33" height="33">&nbsp;<label style="color: #61f6ff;" data-mce-fragment="1">|&nbsp;<a style="color: #001a71;" href="tel:052-6582643" data-mce-fragment="1">&nbsp;052-6582643</a></label></p>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
```

I managed to get eveyrhting in the menu centered, but I"m unable to get the icons and the phone number at the bottom of the menu stay in one line and not break. I also wanna edit it's paddings but it doesn't really work for me.

Here's the menu's CSS:

```
.menu-item-text-mobile {
    -webkit-transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
-moz-transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
-o-transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid transparent; 
border-top: 2.11px solid transparent; 
margin-left:50px;
}


#who-menu-mobile:hover .menu-item-text, 
#who-menu-mobile:focus .menu-item-text, 
#who-menu-mobile:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
}
#solutions-menu-mobile:hover .menu-item-text, 
#solutions-menu-mobile:focus .menu-item-text, 
#solutions-menu-mobile:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
}

#regulation-menu-mobile:hover .menu-item-text, 
#regulation-menu-mobile:focus .menu-item-text, 
#regulation-menu-mobile:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; }

 @media(min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 749px){ .elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title > a{ justify-content: center !important; display: flex !important;
 }}
```

I want the bottom part of the menu to look like this:

[image]

and here you can see the live website: [www.mayabarber.co.il](http://mayabarber.co.il)

I have used a live builder so the HTML is something the builder generated and not something I have written. Therefore, I think the solution should either be a CSS solution or a jQuery one.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It already looks like the one you need.

Comment: Yeah, I solved it by changing the <a style=....> to <span style=...>
Just curious why the a made the line break.

Comment: You could just answer your own question and mark it solved.

Comment: Thanks, I just did. Also thanks for willing to help. :-)

Comment: Good luck :) I hope more questions are incoming related to your site :P

Comment: Haha, just posted one in regard of the Edge browser. I'm going through a learning process here. :-) – Rozi Buber 37 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to solve it by changing the HTML from `<a style=....>` to `<span style=...>`.